# EntityRuler in spacy

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, spacy

I want to extract text which contain ORG, DATE and Location name. How I can do it ?

exp1 - Hcode Technologies, Karnal Haryana
July 2021 to DEC 2021

exp 2 - I am working at VAsitum from jun 1998.

I am thinking about EntityRuler but not able.

I tried with following pattern
pattern = [{"ENT_TYPE": "ORG"}, {"TEXT": {"REGEX": "\s"}, "OP": "{,10}"}, {"ENT_TYPE": "GPE"}]
But not solved.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Regex patterns in spaCy are matched against tokens, not the original string. You can't match ordinary spaces between words with patterns, so that pattern is not doing what you think it is.